# How findIndex and slice method works in react reducer function

Tags: reactjs, function, textfield, crud

I have not clear about the below code of case 'UPDATE_NOTE' - **updateNoteIndex** and **updatedNotes**. Can anyone explain it. This is for updating the text field with the help of case 'UPDATE_NOTE'. Am not understanding the findIndex and slice method in the below code.

```
const NotesContext = React.createContext(
    {
        currentNote: null,
        notes: [
            {id:uuid(), text: 'Do homework'},
            {id:uuid(), text: 'text out trash'},
            {id:uuid(), text: 'clean room'}
        ]
    }
)


case 'UPDATE_NOTE':
            const updateNote = {
                ...state.currentNote,
                text: action.payload
            }

            const updateNoteIndex = state.notes.findIndex (
                note => note.id === state.currentNote.id
            )

            const updatedNotes = [
                ...state.notes.slice(0, updateNoteIndex),
                updateNote,
                ...state.notes.slice(updateNoteIndex + 1)
            ]

            return {
                currentNote: null,
                notes: updatedNotes
            };
```

Comment: It is simply searching first for the index of the element that is being updated, i.e. the index of the current note. The `slice` functions create new array up-to, and after, the found index, both of which are spread into a new array object with the updated current note element between them.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know how slice works?  Take a look at this [quick tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

Basically slice is a method where you can manipulate the array elements. In this example, you need to be familiar with this statement as well:

```
 const foo = [...foo, newFoo]
```

What this does is, it splits the elements inside foo and adds newFoo to it. Therefore:

```
const updatedNotes = [
                ...state.notes.slice(0, updateNoteIndex),
                updateNote,
                ...state.notes.slice(updateNoteIndex + 1)
            ]
```

just replaces the value located in `updateNoteIndex` with `updateNote`

`state.notes.findIndex` is a function to find the index of `note` oject